# unzip Http FormFile in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, zip, azure-blob-storage, azure-http-trigger

I have a front hand in which the user can download a zip. My idea is to use http triggered azure function to unzip that file and send it to Azure blob storage. Therefore I am simulating the http function with postman sending the zip in the form-data. I am not able to figure it out how to go from the Http.FormFile to the unzipped file that I am going to send. I am using c#.

Do you have some suggestion/reference ?

Maybe my approach is wrong and I should send the data(which unzipped is like 60-70 Mb) first to the blob and then use a Blob trigger to send the unzipped file to another container. This last approach feel to me more resource intensive. Which would you choose ?

Comment: The ZIP should be a MIME attachment in the HTTP response.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true.  You can also use FTP to download file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [article](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/02/how-to-unzip-automatically-your-files.html) credits by [FBoucher](https://github.com/FBoucher)

Install the extension from Inside Visual Studio Code and [Azure Function Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) set the setting `AzureWebJobsStorage` to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` in the **local.settings.json** file.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "unziptools_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=unziptools;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    }
}
```

In Azure Function Extension, select your subscription and Function App name under Function App use *`AzUnzipEverything` -> add new setting -> create `cloud5mins_storage`, `destinationStorage` and `destinationContainer`.*

***In your storage account -> resource group -> select your blob -> input files -> upload a zip file***

After few mins uploaded zip file will be Unzipped into the blob storage container output-files.

For your Reference :

https://github.com/FBoucher/AzUnzipEverything by ***FBoucher***